Can a single particle state be entangled?
When I do think of entangled states I usually do think of 2 or more particle states, which can not be written as products of 1 particle states.
But what, if we have just 1 particle being described by a state in a product space? Suppose we send a charge-neutral spin-$\frac{1}{2}$-particle threw a Stern-Gerlach setup and suppose the initial state of the particle was a superposition of the spin up and down states at some initial height: $(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle) \otimes |\psi_{initial}(y)\rangle $. Now after going threw the magnetic field we have a superposition of the spin up and diverted upwards state and the spin down and diverted downwards state: $|\uparrow\rangle \otimes |\psi_{up}(y)\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle \otimes |\psi_{down}(y)\rangle$.
This state is an element of the product space of the spin- and position-Hilbert-spaces, but can not be written as a product of states of the factor-spaces. So from my understanding the mathematical situation is basically the same as when looking at a 2 particle entangled spin state, only the concrete spaces are different. Now my question is am I missing some crucial difference between the 2 situations and if not, would one call the described 1 particle state as “entangled”?

The answer to your question is yes. As long as you have different subspaces that you can measure, and you put them into entangled superposition like you have done above, you can call that state an entangled state. But with just one particle it is difficult to measure the independent correlations that we often want to talk about.

Just to add to naturallyinconsistent’s correct answer: here are a couple of references that touch on the subject. While not necessarily exact to the question, you may find benefit. https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4449   https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.12930

Here is a review on the subject I authored with several collaborators https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/qute.202000014

I will give my mathematically slanted answer. Let's restrict our attention to pure states (as opposed to pure and mixed states). Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote a Hilbert space.

Two systems $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ are entangled when the composite system $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ occupies a state that is not separable, i.e., a state $\lvert \psi \rangle$ that cannot be written as $\lvert \psi_1 \rangle \otimes \psi_2 \rangle$.
Then, by definition entanglement only exists for composite systems. That is, you can only have entanglement when the Hilbert space of the system is a tensor product of Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2 \otimes ...$

I emphasize that entanglement is defined between systems not particles. Now, your systems might represent single particles, but certainly there are systems that are not just single particles.
Hence, if the state you wrote down is not forbidden by any other sort of rules of physics, then it would indeed be described as an entangled state.
In particular, the Hilbert space that represents a single spin-$1/2$ particle is $\mathcal{H}_{1/2} \otimes L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. If your state is physically admissible and the composite  system occupies that state, we'd say that the subsystem $\mathcal{H}_{1/2}$ and the subsystem $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ are entangled.

A particle can have subsystems that can be independently manipulated such as the position and spin of an electron. These subsystems can be made to interact so that information is copied between them and this can generate entanglement. Experiments have been proposed to test such entanglement and such entanglement can violate the Bell inequalities:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0322
https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.08286
https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01058
https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.11797
Single particle entanglement has been observed with photons (thanks to Valter Moretti for pointing this out in a comment):
https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09961

we also proposed such an experiment with photons entangling momentum and polarisation and we experimentally observed the violation of CHSH inequality https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.09961. The result is however related to contextuality and not non locality.

You correctly describe how a Stern-Gerlach apparatus changes a pure incoming state into an entangled state with two outcomes. That is essentially what every measurement does (but Stern-Gerlach is of course a rather famous example in QM!)
We could further add, that since the two spatial wave functions $|\psi_\rm{up}\rangle$ and $|\psi_\rm{down}\rangle$ are usually different from each other on a macroscopic scale, there will be decoherence by environment influences, and your superposition $|\uparrow\rangle \otimes |\psi_\rm{up}(y)\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle \otimes |\psi_\rm{down}(y)\rangle$, while initially pure, will very quickly become a mixed state (which means you can then assume wave function collapse, subjective collapse or objective, as you like...)
The important point is that, while entanglement in a pure quantum system can remain a pure state, in measurements it involves macroscopic scale wave functions and therefore it will not remain pure. Because the measurement device is meant to amplify things to the macroscopic world, the coherence is lost. (Usually. But you can in principle avoid that for some time, it is not
fundamental so we should be cautious with conclusions about the resulting state after measurements.)

What you are describing is an alignment of a single particle under the influence of an external field, often designed as periodic material structures. Examples are optical polarization plates as well as birefringence. Or very obviously designed as a field influence such as the magnetic field in the Stern-Gerlach experiment.
Entanglement, on the other hand, is the mutual alignment of the dipole fields of two particles. This is observed both in electrons, whose magnetic dipoles in the atom are aligned in opposite directions (Pauli's exclusion principle). And it is observed in photons whose oscillating magnetic or electric field components are aligned with each other through the process of spontaneous parametric down-conversion.
Whatever can be described mathematically, it makes no practical sense to attribute entanglement properties to a single particle. Polarized particles are clearly fixed in their direction. Entangled particles, on the other hand, have a randomness in their common alignment with each other. "Up" and "down" therefore do not adequately describe entanglement. It is precisely the common and random orientation of the photons in space that falsifies the result of the forced orientation of the measuring apparatus and only with repeated measurements and statistical methods is the entanglement proven.

Good answer @HolgerFieldler, sometimes people get so caught up in the math they forget they're talking about real physical particles.

I disagree with this answer. The statement that a single particles position and spin are entangled may not always be particularly interesting, but that doesn't mean it is not true

@BillAlsept did you upvote?
